# How to configure Mule 4x Connecters & Components from Mule 3x?

Tags: api, mule, mulesoft, mule4

How to configure Mule 4.x Connecters & Components from Mule 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

Mule 3 and Mule 4 connectors are not compatible. Some built-in components are similar and some will need to be migrated or re implemented. Read the [migration guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/migration-intro) from the official documentation for details.